# Is there some possibility to listen MakerDAO's LogNote events?

Tags: events, ethereum

I wonder is there some possibility to listen LogNote events, like we able to do with standard events.

What I managed to research:

I saw that **LogNote was listed as an event** from contract details

```
let contractIntanse = await new web3.eth.Contract(abi, contractAddress);
console.log("contractIntanse.events: ", contractIntanse.events)

contractIntanse.events:  {
  Approval: [Function: bound ],
  '0x8c5be1e5ebec7d5bd14f71427d1e84f3dd0314c0f7b2291e5b200ac8c7c3b925': [Function: bound ],
  'Approval(address,address,uint256)': [Function: bound ],

  LogNote: [Function: bound ],
  '0xd3d8bec38a91a5f4411247483bc030a174e77cda9c0351924c759f41453aa5e8': [Function: bound ],
  'LogNote(bytes4,address,bytes32,bytes32,bytes)': [Function: bound ],

  Transfer: [Function: bound ],
  '0xddf252ad1be2c89b69c2b068fc378daa952ba7f163c4a11628f55a4df523b3ef': [Function: bound ],
  'Transfer(address,address,uint256)': [Function: bound ],

  allEvents: [Function: bound ]
}
```

However, I was not able to check this properly, e.g:

1. **event.watch** does not work for me because of web3 v1
2. I tried using **WebsocketProvider**

```
web3.eth.subscribe("logs", { address: "0x23..." },
    function(error, result) {
        console.log("subscribe result:",result);
        console.log("subscribe error:",error);
    })
    .on("connected", function(subscriptionId) {
        console.log("subscriptionId:" + subscriptionId);
    })
    .on("data", function(log) {
        console.log("data:" + log);
    })
    .on("changed", function(log) {
        console.log("changed:" + log);
    });
```

However, I was not able to see smth when I trigger event

```
await contractIntanse.methods.rely(address1);
```

Here is related issue I managed to find
https://github.com/ethereum/web3.js/issues/1752

3. I also tried to use **getPastEvents**, as latest `issues/1752` suggested

```
const eventOptions = { filter: {}, fromBlock: 0, toBlock: 'latest' };
const events = await contractIntanse.getPastEvents('LogNote', eventOptions);
```

It works ok for standard event. However, for LogNote I get an error:

```
Error: overflow (operation="setValue", fault="overflow", details="Number can only safely store up to 53 bits")
```

Eventually, I'm very confused, do we able to listen MakerDAO's LogNote?
Appreciate any help, link to docs, discussions etc. Thanks!

Comment: Sounds like a JavaScript issue. JavaScript only supports floating point numbers and can store integers up to 53 bits. EVM supports integers up to 256 bits. The easiest solution I can think of is to write this code in web3.py and Python. Usually web3.js safely handles integers as strings, but I do not know what your code does that it tries to convert it to a number.

Comment: If you call `setValue` yourself pass all numbers as strings.